# Extract feature classes/types from caret train object

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, feature-extraction

Using the built-in iris dataset, I can train a model as such:

```
model <- train(Species~., data=iris, method='xgbTree')
```

I can extract the names of the features, but when I try to get their classes, it returns characters since they are just character strings.

```
model$coefnames
## "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 

lapply(model$coefnames, class)
## "character" "character" "character" "character"
```

However, when you try to put in a variable of another type to make a prediction, it seems as though caret knows the expected type.

```
test<- data.frame(Sepal.Length=1, 
                  Sepal.Width=2, 
                  Petal.Length=3, 
                  Petal.Width="x") # character instead of numeric

predict(model, newdata=test)
## Error: variable 'Petal.Width' was fitted with type "numeric" but type "factor" was supplied
```

Is there any way I can extract the types of the features used to train a model by using just the model object itself? The closest I can get is to use the `dplyr` function `type.convert` but this requires knowing that the inputs will be. My ideal function would operate something like this:

```
model_types(model$coefnames)
##  "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is stored as an attribute of the terms of your model

```
attr(terms(model), "dataClasses")
#      Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#     "factor"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, knew it had to be in there somewhere.